# What is the run time for these codes?? Using Big O

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

I have two functions that I can't seem to understand the Big Notation.

I have written comments on the side of each line, indicating what I think the run time is.

```py
#Question 1
def fn_c(L):
    def helper_c(elem):
        a = [] #O(1)
        for k in range(len(L)): #O(n)
            a.append(elem) #O(1)
        return a #0(1)
    return list(map(helper_c, L)) #O(n)

#Question 2
def fn_d(n):
    ans = 1 #O(1)
    collection = list(range(2*n)) #O(2n)
    #Looping is O(2n)
    for x in collection: #0(n)
        if x%10==1: #O(1)
            ans = ans + 1 #O(1)
        else:
            ans = ans + 2 #O(1)
    return ans
```

I think the first question is O(n^2) and the second is O(2^n). I not really sure though.

Comment: I think you're correct with your estimation.

Comment: Did you mean to write "the second is O(**2n**)" (= O(n))?

Comment: @Noah Ramuscak is this a homework? Is so please state it.

The analysis of the first function is not correct for two reasons: first `append` is amortized `O(1)`, so that need to be stated in the final answer.

Second, the complexity depends on the values present in `L`, so you need to get some bounds for them. Your solution assumes that the length of the lists in `L` is `O(n)`.